# How to register table with geodatabase with a command line?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

Is there a way to register with geodatabase a table stored in an Oracle 11g database, without using ArcMap or Python script?
I'd like to do it with a command line like when registering with ArcSDE (sdelayer -o register ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Only ArcObjects can register tables with a geodatabase (vice registering with ArcSDE, which *can* be done with command line tools). ArcPy *is* the command line for ArcObjects.

The register with geodatabase/ArcSDE dichotomy will dissappear post-10.2 when the now-deprecated ArcSDE command line tools will be eliminated.